# How to solve bot abandoning previously started game from a different user

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am currently in the process of making a blackjack / gambling bot for me and my friends and the bot works, only the problem(screenshot) is that when user A makes a game and user B makes a Game when user A responds after that user User B has started a game, the original game from user A gets abandoned and takes Users A's response and applies to User

[image: Screenshot problem]

I currently have an active game list which tracks who is in an active game and puts them in/out of one when they complete or start a game but this only solves it when a users is not an in game.

I have edited the code down below to make it less obstructed by a lot of repetitive code

any suggestions on how to fix this code for this problem will be welcome.

```
from datetime import datetime
import string
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import sqlite3

class BlackjackCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.game_id = "AAAAAAAA"
        self.players_in_game = {}
        self.deck = []
        self.reset_deck()
        self.player_hand = None
        self.dealer_hand = None
        self.outcome = ""
        self.timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.bet = None
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("credits.db")
        self.conn2 = sqlite3.connect("logs.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor2 =self.conn2.cursor()
    def unload(self):
        self.conn.close()
        self.conn2.close()

    def check_hand_value(self, hand)
       # game logic to count cards
     
    def reset_deck 
       # game logic to prevent the deck from going empty
    
    def draw_card
       # game logic to append a card to the current player or reset the deck if its empty

    @commands.command(name="bj", aliases=["Bj", "blackjack", "BJ" , "Blackjack"])
    async def blackjack(self, ctx, bet_amount: int = None):
        user_id = ctx.author.id
        if bet_amount is None:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Example Higher Lower" , color=0x3498db)

            embed.add_field(name="How to Play", value="`You need to get higher amount of card total than the dealer's hand`", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Aliases", value="`!hit , !stand`", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Win value", value="`x2`", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Example command", value="`!bj <credit amount>`", inline=False)
    
            embed.set_footer(text='Do !bj for this message')

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        if bet_amount <= 0:
            await ctx.send("Invalid bet amount. Please enter a positive number.")
            return

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT credits FROM credits WHERE user_id=?", (ctx.author.id,))
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            await ctx.send("You do not have any credits use !daily ")
            return

        self.player_credits = result[0]
        if result is None:
            await ctx.send("You do not have any credits. Please add some with !daily")
            return

        if bet_amount > result[0]:
            await ctx.send("You do not have enough credits to make that bet.")
            return

        if ctx.author.id in self.players_in_game:
            await ctx.send("You are already in a game. Please finish your current game before starting a new one.")
            return

        self.bet_amount = bet_amount

        self.player_hand = [self.draw_card(), self.draw_card()]
        self.dealer_hand = [self.draw_card(), self.draw_card()]

        player_total = self.check_hand_value(self.player_hand)
        dealer_total = self.check_hand_value([self.dealer_hand[0]])

        bet_amount = "{:,}".format(bet_amount)
        player_credits = "{:,}".format(self.player_credits)

        self.game_id = "BJ" + "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))
        self.msg = await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="Blackjack | " + 'User: ' + ctx.author.display_name + " - ID: " + self.game_id, color=0x3498db)
            .add_field(name="Your hand", value=' '.join(self.player_hand) + f"\nTotal: **{player_total}**", inline=True)
            .add_field(name="Dealers hand", value=' '.join([self.dealer_hand[0]])+ f"\nTotal: **{dealer_total}**", inline=True)
            .add_field(name="Bet", value=f"**{bet_amount}** credits", inline=False)
            .add_field(name="Credits", value=f"You have **{player_credits}** credits", inline=False)
            .add_field(name="Options", value="Use !hit \nUse !stand \nUse !split\n Use !dd", inline=False)
            .set_footer(text='Active game')
        )
        self.players_in_game[user_id] = {}
        
    @commands.command(names="hit", aliases=["h", "Hit" , "H"])
    async def hit(self, ctx):
        user_id = ctx.author.id
        if user_id not in self.players_in_game:
            await ctx.send("You don't have an active game to stand in.")
            return
        game_id = self.players_in_game[user_id]
        player_hand = self.player_hand
        player_hand.append(self.draw_card())
        player_total = self.check_hand_value(player_hand)
        dealer_total = self.check_hand_value([self.dealer_hand[0]])
        self.player_hand2 = "Empty"
        self.player_hand_str = " ".join(self.player_hand)
        self.dealer_hand_str = " ".join(self.dealer_hand)
        if player_total > 21:
            self.outcome = "Lost hit"
            self.player_credits -= self.bet_amount
            bet_amount = "{:,}".format(self.bet_amount)
            player_credits = "{:,}".format(self.player_credits)
            self.cursor.execute(f"UPDATE credits SET credits = {self.player_credits} WHERE user_id=?", (ctx.author.id,))
            self.conn.commit()
            self.cursor2.execute("""INSERT INTO blackjack_logs (game_id, player_hand, player_hand2 ,dealer_hand, player_credits ,bet_amount, outcome, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (self.game_id, self.player_hand_str, self.player_hand2, self.dealer_hand_str, self.player_credits ,self.bet_amount,self.outcome, self.timestamp,))
            self.conn2.commit()
            await self.msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title="Blackjack | " + 'User: ' + ctx.author.display_name+ " - ID: " + self.game_id , color=0xe74c3c)
                .add_field(name="Your hand", value=' '.join(self.player_hand) + f"\nTotal: **{player_total}**", inline=True)
                .add_field(name="Dealers hand", value=' '.join([self.dealer_hand[0]])+ f"\nTotal: **{dealer_total}**", inline=True)
                .add_field(name="Lost", value=f"**{bet_amount}** credits", inline=False)
                .add_field(name="Credits", value=f"You have **{player_credits}** credits", inline=False)
                .set_footer(text='Finished game')
            )
            del self.players_in_game[ctx.author.id]
            self.player_hand = None
            self.dealer_hand = None
            self.bet_amount = None
        elif player_total == 21:
            self.outcome = "Won hit"
            self.player_credits += self.bet_amount
            bet_amount = "{:,}".format(self.bet_amount)
            player_credits = "{:,}".format(self.player_credits)
            self.cursor.execute(f"UPDATE credits SET credits = {self.player_credits} WHERE user_id=?", (ctx.author.id,))
            self.conn.commit()
            self.cursor2.execute("""INSERT INTO blackjack_logs (game_id, player_hand, player_hand2 ,dealer_hand, player_credits ,bet_amount, outcome, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (self.game_id, self.player_hand_str, self.player_hand2, self.dealer_hand_str, self.player_credits ,self.bet_amount,self.outcome, self.timestamp,))
            self.conn2.commit()
            await self.msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title="Blackjack | " + 'User: ' + ctx.author.display_name + " - ID: " + self.game_id, color=0x109319)
                .add_field(name="Your hand", value=' '.join(self.player_hand) + f"\nTotal: **{player_total}**", inline=True)
                .add_field(name="Dealers hand", value=' '.join([self.dealer_hand[0]])+ f"\nTotal: **{dealer_total}**", inline=True)
                .add_field(name="Win", value=f"**{bet_amount}** credits", inline=False)
                .add_field(name="Credits", value=f"You have **{player_credits}** credits", inline=False)
                .set_footer(text='Finished game')
            )
            del self.players_in_game[ctx.author.id]
            self.player_hand = None
            self.dealer_hand = None
            self.bet_amount = None
        else:
            bet_amount = "{:,}".format(self.bet_amount)
            player_credits = "{:,}".format(self.player_credits)
            await self.msg.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title="Blackjack | " + 'User: ' + ctx.author.display_name + " - ID: " + self.game_id, color=0x3498db)
                .add_field(name="Your hand", value=' '.join(self.player_hand) + f"\n**Total: **{player_total}", inline=True)
                .add_field(name="Dealers hand", value=' '.join([self.dealer_hand[0]])+ f"\n**Total: **{dealer_total}", inline=True)
                .add_field(name="Bet", value=f"**{bet_amount}** credits", inline=False)
                .add_field(name="Credits", value=f"You have **{player_credits}** credits", inline=False)
                .add_field(name="Options", value="Use !hit \n Use !stand\nUse !dd", inline=False)
                .set_footer(text='Active game')
            )
```

I also have stand, split and dd command but this amount of code should be enough to give suggestions/edits I believe.

I have tried to edit and add multiple active game lists and assigned an id to to player in the active game list but that also hasn't worked and I tried looking for a basic solution only

So far my conclusion is that I will need to implement a while loop and edit standard bj function and make it all run in 1 command instead of multiple.

The game itself works fine if you are playing solo the problem is really the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, these are all the class variables you have (that are important to a "game"):

- `game_id`
- `players_in_game`
- `deck`
- `player_hand`
- `dealer_hand`
- `outcome`

Now, let's run through some players playing your game. **Player A** comes along and does `blackjack`. This initialises all those above variables with values for them. If they were to keep playing by themselves - it would work just fine. However, before **Player A** can do anything, **Player B** comes along and runs the `blackjack` command. This overwrites all the values you had for **Player A** stored in those variables. If **Player A** now calls one of your other commands, they'll be using game state from **Player B**'s game.

There's a fundamental flaw in your logic and saving of game state that'll always fail when more than one player tries to play at the same time.

What you need to do, is create some sort of `game state` object that can be used for that. This can be as simple as a `dict`, a custom class, DB entry, etc. But it needs to be something.

Using the `dict` idea:

```py
# when a user uses the `blackjack` command
player_game_state = {"game_id": game_id, "user_id": user_id, "player_hand": player_hand, "dealer_hand": dealer_hand, "bet": bet} # etc, etc, etc
```

Then, we *actually* use your `self.players_in_game` class variable to keep track of all these game states.

```py
# still in the blackjack command - once you setup everything
self.players_in_game[user_id] = game_state
```

Now, when they call one of the other commands, like `hit`:

```py
# at the start of the command
player_game_state = self.players_in_game[user_id]

# instead of doing self.player_hand
player_game_state["player_hand"].append(self.draw_card())
```

Though, maybe your `draw_card` method, and `reset_deck` methods need to take the game state as a parameter and modify them. As I'd wager they're currently resetting your class variables as well.

Does that make sense? Hopefully enough that you can try to apply some of it.

TLDR; stop using class variables for storing individual parts of your game state.

Comment: Used your advise and it worked didnt need to add alot the only leftover bug was that you also needed to include the msg in the dict and then it all worked. Thanks alot for the help